# Give element name programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to each element I add a unique name which I get from the loop. How can I accomplish it? The line 2 is where is the error.

```
foreach (var station in stations) {
 TextBlock station.name = new TextBlock(); // error !!!                        
}
```

Comment: The error itself could perhaps be useful...

Comment: What is the purpose of the "unique name"? So you can use it like a regular variable in your code-behind? So you can access it from your markup (the XAML)? Just for the sake of giving it a name for reports?

Comment: Explaining the problem you are trying to solve would help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead...

```
TextBlock station = new TextBlock() { Name="Something" };
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you want to do...  Are you trying to create controls for each member of a collection?  If that's what you're doing, try looking at a ListBox, or a more generic ItemsPresenter control, and the ItemTemplate property of that element.

For example, add a ListBox to your XAML, and assign stations as it's ItemsSource, then add a DataTemplate to represent the items.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding stations}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to create an new instance of textblock on the name property of the textblock instance station.

That is definitely not going to work.

Try:

`TextBlock station = new TextBlock();
station.name = "Whatever name you want";`